# MSVC /FA GCC equivalent

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

I'm using GCC to compiler and I want to print the full path of the file using `__FILE__`, but GCC shows only the name of the file. In MSVC is the same, but you can use an argument [/FC (Full Path of Source Code File in Diagnostics)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s.aspx) and it works. Is there any equivalent to GCC?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << __FILE__ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any equivalent, but I realized that `__FILE__` macro expands to the name of the current input file via the path used by the preprocessor to open the file. So it will depend on what is passed to the compiler.

I solved it using `CMake` as build system. When `CMake` creates the MakeFile it uses the full path in the variable `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, this way `__FILE__` will print exactly what we expect.